# satisfying a system of DEs related to $(fg)'=f'g'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a general solution (if it exists) to the system of equations:
$$(fg)'=f'g'$$
$$(fg)''=f''g''$$
we can obviously rewrite these as:
$$fg'+gf'=f'g'$$
$$fg''+gf''+2f'g'=f''g''$$
I am not really sure how to go from here without substituting one into the other and seeing what happens e.g:
$$fg''+gf''+2fg'+2gf'-f''g''=0$$

---

It is also easy to assume certain things about each function and get a specific solution out e.g. $g''=0$ but this does not help with the general solution. My final thought was to write it as:
$$\frac{g''}{g'}=\frac{f''}{f''-f'}$$

Comment: I think it is answered in this YouTube comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYFJV3Fatqk&lc=Ugylfrx7VfEQOJ-5EmJ4AaABAg

Comment: That is great thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(fg)'=f'g' \implies f'g+fg'=f'g' \implies \frac{f}{f'}+\frac{g}{g'} = 1$$
One possibility is $$\frac{f}{f'}=c \implies \frac{g}{g'}=1-c$$
Then we get $$f(x)=Ae^{x/c}, ~~~g(x)=B e^{x/(1-c)}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(fg)'=f'g'$$
$$f'g+fg'=f'g'$$
For $f \ne 0$
$$(\ln f)'(g-g')=-g'$$
$$\ln f=-\int \dfrac {g'}{g-g'}dx+C$$
You can choose $g$ as you want and find $f$.